# Homology of $Σ_g × S^1$ w.r.t. real coefficients

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I'm trying to calculate this homology $H_{n}(Σ_g × S^1;\mathbb R)$, but I can't figure out how it looks like.

I used the Mayer–Vietoris sequence, but I'm not sure my answer is correct.

I'll be happy for some help!

Tnx.

Comment: [Since $\Bbb R$ is a field $\text{ for all }k\geq 0$ we have $$H_k(\Sigma_g\times S^1;\Bbb R)\simeq \bigoplus_{i+j=k}H_i(\Sigma_g;\Bbb R)\otimes_\Bbb R H_j(S^1;\Bbb R).$$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%BCnneth_theorem)

Comment: [Now use this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2323742/computing-the-homology-of-genus-g-surface-using-mayer-vietoris)